# Using multiple arrayFilters on the same top-level field in MongoDB with Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update a nested document in MongoDB based on certain conditions. The problem is that using arrayFilters on the same top-level field name is not allowed. Any solutions for solving this problem?

`Error: Found multiple array filters with the same top-level field name x`

```
    filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "_id", Value: e.EventId}}

    arrayFilters := options.ArrayFilters{
        Filters: []interface{}{
            bson.M{"x._id": tt.TypeId},
            bson.M{"x.typeAmountUsed": bson.M{"$lt": "$x.typeAmount"}}, // <-- multiple filters
        },
    }

    upsert := true
    opts := options.UpdateOptions{
        ArrayFilters: &arrayFilters,
        Upsert:       &upsert,
    }
    update := bson.M{
        "$inc": bson.D{{"eventTicketTypes.$[x].typeAmountUsed", 1}},
    }

    if _, err = events.UpdateOne(sessCtx, filter, update, &opts); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple criteria in the same filter, combine them into a single filter.
See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#specify-arrayfilters-for-array-update-operations

However, arrayFilters do not support directly comparing 2 fields within the array element.  You might be able to accomplish that with $map.